# Getting molly-guard to work with sudo

Tags: ssh, debian, sudo, reboot

The program `molly-guard` is a brilliant little tool which will prompt you for a piece of information before you reboot or shut down a system. Usually it asks for the hostname. So when you work a lot via SSH, you won't end up taking down the wrong server, just because you were in the wrong tab or window.

Now, this works all fine when you say `reboot` on the command line while you are already `root`. However, it won't work if you do `sudo reboot` (i.e. it won't even ask). How can I get it to work with `sudo` as well?

System: Raspbian (latest, including updates), package `molly-guard` version `0.4.5-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mollyguard basically works by placing scripts in `/usr/sbin/*`.  These scripts call the actual shutdown/halt/reboot binaries that are stored in `/sbin`.  Sudo or the root on your system is probably set with a `PATH` that has /sbin before `/usr/sbin/` in the effective PATH.  Adjust your path so that `/usr/sbin/` is first.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the combination of `sudo` and `tmux` that stopped it detecting the SSH session. (It also affects `screen` the same way - this is a known issue listed in `man molly-guard`.)

I solved it by adding this to the `sudoers` config file (using the `visudo` command):

```
Defaults env_keep += SSH_CONNECTION
```